# Can anyone tell me if there are any logic gates built into this circuit board?

Tags: led, digital-logic, board

We have these circuit boards that we use at work for indication of whether a door is open or closed... To be honest, I have no idea how they work.  I drew up a diagram of it to see if anyone can explain how it works.  The left LED is green (closed) and the right LED is red (open).  I've added a picture to show you what I'm talking about.  Thank you so very much for your help!

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCrlxh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: It's really hard to see the LEDs, but they are both pointing in the same direction]

[image: Underside of where all the doors are operated]

Comment: Looks like maybe a diode gate. Primitive stuff, but effective.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate?  I'm not too savvy when it comes to this stuff... Which section looks like a logic gate?  Is it AND or OR?

Comment: It's just a general feeling. You'd need to draw out a schematic to be certain.

Comment: @WesleyLee I think I did that right... I'm not an expert, but that looks like the circuit board?

Comment: It does look like the circuit board to me. What are the terminals connected to? If I have time I'll come back later and try to organize the schematic a bit.

Comment: Okay, the far right side (I think) is positive power.  The inner right side gets daisy chained to other circuit board terminals in the same place.  The inner left side can also be daisy chained to other circuit boards in the same place.  The far left is (I think) negative... Again, I'm not sure of any of that, but I'm doing the best I can.

Comment: What is this board connected to?  How does it know if the door is open or closed?

Comment: @PeterBennett it is hooked up to a NO-NC switch that the door activates & deactivates on the closed side of the door.  So, when the door is closed the green LED (left side) should light up, and when it leaves that closed switch, the red LED (right side) should light up.  I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Please show the door switch and power supply connections on your drawing.

Comment: @PeterBennett Okay, I have to physically go to one of the doors, so I can see it and draw it out, I will add it to my drawing when I am able to get that done.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong with your schematic... Recheck  the diode polarities.. or post a pick of the board. D4 and D8 cant both be pointing the same way.

Comment: @Trevor I added the pictures.

Comment: @Trevor I also added a photo of what the inside of the panel looks like... The circuit boards are literally just for the function of showing whether a door is opened or closed.

Comment: D3 must be backwards though or it would never light with D2 in parallel

Comment: @Trevor It's hard to see, but the pictures show that both LEDs are facing the same direction.

Comment: Ya that is fine, but your schematic is wrong.

Comment: Could you put a photo of the back of the PCB?

Comment: The green led also looks like it was replaced, it may be in backwards in the photo.

Answer (score 4):

I your LED, D3, is drawn backwards, or it will never light with D2 in parallel with it.

Best I can figure is your schematic is better drawn this way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDf5km.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The terminal between the resistors could be being connected to either live or neutral via a SPDT switch. That will light the appropriate LED during the appropriate half cycle. Since the circuit has no current return path otherwise, something must be hooking in to the power lines via those terminals and this way works.... The terminal is marked C, being common I presume.

Not sure what the terminal between D5 and D6 does, though it could be a test thing as shown. Since these things are mounted on a panel, if the T connection (There is a hint :) were daisy chained together to a rectifier through the shown button, pressing the button would cause all the LEDs to be lit.